# Django DRF create user

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to serialize a `CreateUserSerializer(ModelSerializer)`
My code is as follows. My problem is that it will only create a `User` and not a `UserProfile`.

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    """
    Many other attributes like display_name, dob, hometown, etc
    """
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CreateUserProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
                validated_data['username'],
                validated_data['email'],
                validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        user_profile = UserProfile(user=user)
        user_profile.save()
        return user_profile
```

And in my views it goes as follows...

`api/views.py`

```
class RegistrationAPI(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreateUserProfileSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserProfileSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,

        })
```

If you follow the code, the Response will give me a

> "RelatedManager has no attribute 'pk'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `serializer.py` as below

```
class CreateUserProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
```

Comment: Hello, this does not work. Still only creates a User object but no UserProfile object. @Jerin Peter George

Comment: Nope, you are wrong. It will create a `User` instance and it will be assigned/mapped to a **newly created `UserProfile` instance** . Check your `Django Admin` or `Django shell` if you want

Comment: You are right. It does work. I apologize. I forgot I was playing around with it and changed up the Serializer in the api/views.py. Thank you.